# find if a number divisible by the input numbers

Tags: python, data-structures

Given two numbers a and b, we have to find the nth number which is divisible by a or b.

**The format looks like below:**

**Input :**
First line consists of an integer T, denoting the number of test cases.
Second line contains three integers a, b and N

**Output :**
For each test case, print the Nth
number in a new line.

**Constraints :**

1≤t≤105

1≤a,b≤104

1≤N≤10

**Sample Input**

1

2 3 10

**Sample Output**

15

**Explanation**

The numbers which are divisible by 2
or 3 are: 2,3,4,6,8,9,10,12,14,15 and the 10th number is 15

**My code**

```
test_case=input()

if int(test_case)<=100000 and  int(test_case)>=1:
    for p in range(int(test_case)):
        count=1
        j=1

        inp=list(map(int,input().strip('').split()))
        if inp[0]<=10000 and  inp[0]>=1 and  inp[1]<=10000 and  inp[1]>=1 and inp[1]<=1000000000 and  inp[1]>=1:
            while(True ):
             if count<=inp[2] :
               k=j
               if j%inp[0]==0 or j%inp[1] ==0:
                   count=count+1
                   j=j+1

               else       :
                   j=j+1
             else:
                 break
            print(k)     
        else:
            break
```

**Problem Statement:**
For single test case input 2000 3000 100000 it is taking more than one second to complete.I want if i can get the results in less than 1 second. Is there a time efficient approach to this problem,may be if we can use some data structure and algorithms here??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain to grasp exactly what you're trying to accomplish. But if I get it right, isn't the answer simply b*(N/2)? since you are listing the multiples of both numbers the Nth will always be the second you list times N/2.

In your initial example that would be 3*10/2=15.
In the code example, it would be 3000*100000/2=150'000'000

**Update:**
Code to compute the desired values using set's and lists to speed up the calculation process. I'm still wondering what the recurrence for the odd indexes could be if anyone happens to stumble upon it...

```
a = 2000
b = 3000
c = 100000

a_list = [a*x for x in range(1, c)]
b_list = [b*x for x in range(1, c)]

nums = set(a_list)
nums.update(b_list)

nums = sorted(nums)

print(nums[c-1])
```

This code runs in 0.14s on my laptop. Which is significantly below the requested threshold. Nonetheless, this values will depend on the machine the code is run on.

Comment: if i go with 2 3 5 and converting to your equation it would be 3*5/2 which is equal to 7.5 .it should have been 8 obviously we can round of but don't know in how many cases it will pass

Comment: Oh right, I haven't accounted for the odd case, sorry. Basically all even N will be a multiple of b and all odd N a multiple of a.

Comment: Hmm, I can't find the recurrence to save my life :) I have updated my initial comment with a faster code than yours.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Pat . Your first update is still running more than one sec if go with higher value of a,b and k and for your second update it's throwing **list index out of range error**

Comment: Sorry my second update was horribly wrong indeed. I removed it, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

For every two numbers there will be number `k` such that `k=a*b`. There will only be so many multiples of `a` and `b` under `k`. This set can be created like so:

```
s = set(a*1, b*1, ... a*(b-1), b*(a-1), a*b)
```

Say we take the values `a=2, b=3` then `s = (2,3,4,6)`. These are the possible values of `c`:

```
[1 - 4]  => (2,3,4,6)
[5 - 8]  => 6 + (2,3,4,6)
[9 - 12] => 6*2 + (2,3,4,6)
...
```

Notice that the values repeat with a predictable pattern. To get the row you can take the value of `c` and divide by length of the set `s` (call it `n`). The set index is the mod of `c` by `n`. Subtract `1` for `1` indexing used in the problem.

```
row = floor((c-1)/n)
column = `(c-1) % n`
result = (a*b)*row + s(column)
```

Python impl:

```
a = 2000
b = 3000
c = 100000
s = list(set([a*i for i in range(1, b+1)] + [b*i for i in range(1, a+1)]))
print((((c-1)//len(s)) * (a*b)) + s[(c - 1)%len(s)])
```